# Server 2012 multiple NICs for VMs

Tags: networking, windows-server-2012-r2, virtualbox

I'm trying to setup a Windows server 2012 machine with multiple VMs (10+).
The server also has 2 on-board NICs and 4 more via pci-e card.

My main goal is to have the on-board NIC be available only to the host, and the other 4 be available only to the VMs, and additionally split the 4 ports among the different VMs (this I can do with virtualbox manager).

Is there any way I can do this? Can I isolate different network connection, or at least give some more priority over others?

Comment: Why are you using VirtualBox instead of Hyper-V?

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is to team the network cards and then build your virtual switch on top of that network team. What type of teaming you need etc will depend on your network switches but the following article will explain how to do it.

http://www.msserverpro.com/configuring-windows-server-2012-nic-teaming-to-a-hyper-v-virtual-machine/

EDIT:

This article explains much more, and goes into QOS. While it talks about 10Gb the principals are the same

http://www.hyper-v.nu/archives/mvaneijk/2013/01/lbfo-hyper-v-switch-qos-and-actual-performance-part-1/